# Adding items to LinearLayout (and resizing)

Tags: android

I have the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#0f0"
        android:id="@+id/bed_list"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:text="Howdy cowboy?"
        android:textSize="50dip"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/textview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to add some textviews to R.id.bed_list (as if they were vertical tabs)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

  LinearLayout bedList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bed_list);

  for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    System.out.println("In the loop");
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("HJM-" + i);
    textView.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textView.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    bedList.addView(textView,i,
      new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  }
}
```

So far, the code is run, the System.out.println messages in the loop appear at the console, but I only see the textview (`R.id.textview`). I wanted the list to appear at the left of the screen with the options calculated, but it does not work.

Further on, if I define a first textview in the label (so that there is some items at the very beginning and a space is reserved), I get to see that textview but the others (added from the program) do not appear either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textview (R.id.textview) has a width of `match_parent`, effectively pushing your other views (the linearlayout) off screen. Instead you can give it a width of `wrap_content` and possibly a `layout_weight` of 1.

Comment: Ok, I thought "match_parent" would work as "*" in HTML and would not override other views "wrap_content". Anyway the views I add programmatically still are not shown.

Comment: nah, "match_parents" makes the view take all possible space. You can also try using the addChild(textView, i) without the layoutparams, and especially without the setWidth() and setHeight() which tries to set the width/height to 0 or whatever the WRAP_CONTENT constant is. You can set the layoutparams width and height this way, but not the view.

Comment: Ok, you were right. But now items don't fill the `bedList` LinearLayout. Any easy way (other than fixed/program calculated width) so I can make the list expand AND make all the items `match_parent`. If not, maybe I'll switch to GridView

Comment: Try using the addChild() method you used first, but with width as MATCH_PARENT.